# Template Engine and Unexpected string constant in IE8 - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, template-engine

I've got huge problem when doing HTML compilation with Template Engine build in JavaScript.

Everything is working for Chrome, FF. 
IE8 works just in one case - when my HTML is set as variable.

Scenario for HTML:

1). Below example works in all browsers (even in IE8)

```
var phone_tpl = '<div class="demobile-view">'+
    '<div class="heading clearfix">'+
        '<span class="attention">{{& attention}}</span>'+
        '<h4>aaa</h4>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';
```

2). Below example work in CHrome, FF. IE8 won't work with it.

```
<script type="text/template" id="phone_tpl">
    <div class="demobile-view">
        <div class="heading clearfix">
            <span class="attention">{{& attention}}</span>
            <h4>aaa</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Second point in IE8 console responds with error "Unterminated string constant".

I'm attaching full package of library + init example.

http://jsfiddle.net/2trv57rk/

Really believe that someone will be able to help me :) I hate writing HTML in quotes :) I need to have clear, well-coded alternative.

Thank you in advance !!